# MySQL Trigger to Update a field in one table after inserting into another

Tags: mysql, triggers

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijIsx.jpg)

I have the two tables above. In tblUniformAndMaterials the field AllocatedMaterials is populated from a drop down list which is fed by from tblMaterials. Once selected  the field MaterialID in tblUniformAndMaterials is Auto Populated from tblMaterials. 
What I want to accomplish by using a Trigger is after the record in tblUniformAndMaterials is inserted I want to update the NiveauDeStock field in tblMaterials to (NiveauDeStock-1). In other words after each material allocation I reduce the stock level by one.

Answer (score 0):

Reference for `CREATE TRIGGER` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tblUniformAndMaterials_ai 
AFTER INSERT 
ON tblUniformAndMaterials 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE tblMaterials
set NiveauDeStock = NiveauDeStock -1
WHERE CodeDeMaterial = NEW.MaterialID;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note `AFTER INSERT` and how `NEW.MaterialID` is the ID inserted into tblUniformAndMaterials.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Kevin, almost there but CodeDeMaterial is irrelevant I need to match the newly inserted MaterialID with the correct record in tblMaterials so I assume I would just replace it with MaterialID? I still have an error but I am checking a possible cause for that now.

Comment: @Carl WOW - not sure how I missed that.  Yes, `WHERE MaterialID = NEW.MaterialID`

Comment: No worries. It's all up and running fine. Cheers